# SQL VIEW formatting XML Field Type

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am such a noob and to me this seems like it should be simple but I have pulled out even my last hair trying to figure it out.

SQL view returns

- Table `Announcements`
- Column `tp_ColumnSet`
- Type `XML`

Data:

```
<datetime1>2014-11-06T08:00:00</datetime1>
<ntext2>&lt;div class="ExternalClass92FCE11907AF41979E054BE04236CCBE"&gt;&lt;p&gt;Open Enrollment Meeting Wednesday, November 5th at 2pm. John Doe will be here to go over our 2014-2015 Medical/Dental &amp;amp; Life Insurance plans and our 401K Plan. We will also have a representative from Joe Medical joining us. Please plan to attend!&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</ntext2>
<nvarchar1>Open Enrollment Meeting</nvarchar1>
```

I am trying to display in a view

Field Title

Open Enrollment Meeting

Field Body

Open Enrollment Meeting Wednesday, November 5th at 2pm. John Doe will be here to go over our 2014-2015 Medical/Dental &amp; Life Insurance plans and our 401K Plan. We will also have a representative from Joe Medical joining us. Please plan to attend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract nodes from an XML field via its [value()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178030.aspx) method. You basically provide an XQuery to the node you're interested in along with a preferred SQL type it should be returned as.

```
select tp_ColumnSet.value('(/data/datetime1)[1]', 'datetime') as TheDate
     , tp_ColumnSet.value('(/data/nvarchar1)[1]', 'nvarchar(200)') as TheTitle
     , tp_ColumnSet.value('(/data/ntext2)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as TheBody
from Announcements
```

Note that I've also assumed the root node is `<data>`, so you may need to adjust the code to suit.

This returns:

```
2014-11-06 08:00:00.000
Open Enrollment Meeting
<div class="ExternalClass92FCE11907AF41979E054BE04236CCBE"><p>Open Enrollment Meeting Wednesday, November 5th at 2pm. John Doe will be here to go over our 2014-2015 Medical/Dental &amp; Life Insurance plans and our 401K Plan. We will also have a representative from Joe Medical joining us. Please plan to attend!</p></div>
```

Comment: Only need to find my root node now I think.  The query is working just all NULL

Comment: Have you updated the XQuery to match your XML structure as per the note on `<data>`? My answer assumes its `<data><datetime1>...</datetime1><ntext2>...</ntext2><nvarchar1>...</nvarchar1></data>`